# Handle multiple SP metadata generators in SAML

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have SP initiated SAML 2.0 + SPRING boot application working behind the Load balancer. The load balancer end point (http://myserver.biz) is configured  as entityBaseUrl for the application as

```
metadataGenerator.setEntityBaseURL(http://myserver.biz);
```

We added reverse proxy over the LB now which customer will be connecting to over internet. The proxy end point is https://myserverproxy.com. Now I configured entitybase url to something like
    metadataGenerator.setEntityBaseURL(https://myserverproxy.com);

The trouble is internal customer will be using application url as http://myserver.biz while external customers coming over internet will use https://myserverproxy.com.

I am unable to configure two entityBaseUrls for the application, SAML MetadataGenerator class support only one entity base url at a time.

```
public class MetadataGenerator {

    private String id;
    private String entityId;
    private String entityBaseURL;
...
```

}

How can this be achieved? Any solution on this?

```
@Bean
public MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator() {
    MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
    metadataGenerator.setEntityId(entityId);
    metadataGenerator.setExtendedMetadata(extendedMetadata());
    metadataGenerator.setIncludeDiscoveryExtension(false);
    metadataGenerator.setKeyManager(keyManager());
    metadataGenerator.setEntityBaseURL(entityBaseUrl);

    return metadataGenerator;
}
```